# Does presence of many polygons on X11 window buffer slow down drawing of other GUI elements?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

We are working on a legacy X-Windows/Motif application to show real-time air traffic (flights) and convective weather in the form of polygons. The app is double-buffered, with the back buffer containing the map elements and weather polygons, and the front buffer showing the flight information. Each 200 ms loop, the back buffer is copied to the front buffer before updating the front buffer with flight data.

We find that the drawing of the flight symbols on the canvas is far more variable in time when the polygons are visible. So what should take microsecs sometimes takes over 100 ms, which means the GUI can't complete its tasks in the 200 ms loop.

We are running the app over a Remote Desktop (X2Go), which, despite lots of compression, definitely makes the problem more obvious.

I have timed the actual polygon drawing code, and it only takes 4-6 ms. But the polygons' presence seems to have a huge effect on drawing of OTHER elements, the flight symbols. So out of 600 symbols, most take a few microsecs, while 6-8 take 100 ms each in a 200-ms loop. This causes the app to become unusable.

The code below shows how the polygons are drawn (each) and how each flight symbol is drawn, as a character.

```
void
draw_lines(draw_window win_ptr, color color_ptr,
    XPoint *const points, const int npoints, const int thickness)
{
    x_draw_window  *draw = (x_draw_window *) win_ptr;
    GC color = (GC) color_ptr;

    if (thickness > 0)
    {
        XSetLineAttributes(draw->display, color, thickness, LineSolid,
            CapNotLast, JoinRound);
    }
    else
    {
        XSetLineAttributes(draw->display, color, 1, LineSolid,
             CapNotLast, JoinRound);
    }
    XDrawLines(draw->display, draw->window, color, points, npoints,
        CoordModeOrigin);
    return;
 }

void
draw_text(draw_window win_ptr, color color_ptr,
    char *font, int x, int y, char *text)
{
    x_draw_window  *draw;
    GC color;
    XTextItem t_item;
    unsigned long valuemask;
    XGCValues values;

    draw = (x_draw_window *) win_ptr;
    color   = (GC) color_ptr;

    t_item.chars = text;
    t_item.nchars = strlen(text);
    t_item.delta = 0;
    t_item.font = None;

    valuemask = GCFont;
    values.font = (Font)font;
    XChangeGC(draw->display, color, valuemask, &values);

    if (text != NULL && strcmp(text, "\0"))
    {
        XDrawText(draw->display, draw->window, color, x, y, &t_item, 1);
    }
}
```

My question is for anyone who know the internals of Xlib... would it be expected that the time to complete XDrawText can vary by orders of magnitude when there are hundreds of polygons somewhere else on the same buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience with similar application, you can speedup the application by avoiding the repeated changes to the GC. Instead, create a number of predefined read-only GC, and use them for the drawing requests.